# Taking Formatted input using sscanf with optional whitespaces

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read input from subtitle files(STL format) where the string format is of the form:

1) `00:00:37:09 , 00:00:39:24 , Subtitle Text.` (i.e with spaces b/w the time and text)

Another format of the same subtitle format is

2 ) `00:00:31:02,00:00:33:00,Subtitle Text.` (i.e without any spaces b/w the time and text)

To read the line I am doing the following:

```
sscanf(*buf, "%2d:%2d:%2d:%2d , %2d:%2d:%2d:%2d , %n",
&hh1, &mm1, &ss1, &ms1, &hh2, &mm2, &ss2, &ms2, &len)
```

This however reads the text wrong if the subtitle file has a mixture of 1) and 2) or if the file has some other combination of whitespaces. How should I read the input to ignore the whitespaces?

Comment: It seems like there is no problem. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/ukjW7V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `buf` is a variant on `char **buf` (a double pointer to `char`), the code should be OK — as long as your 'milliseconds' fields (inferred from the use of `&ms1` and `&ms2` as variable names) never have more than 2 digits.  The white space appearing explicitly in the format string means 'optional white space'.  It is technically redundant before the `%2d` but does no harm.

Your fragment has one open parenthesis and two close parentheses.  I assume it means you are using it in a context such as:

```
int rc;
if ((rc = sscanf(…)) != 8)
    …oops — malformatted data…
else
    …pick up subtitle from `(*buf)[len]` onwards…
```

If you are having problems, you need to show the data that causes the trouble.  You could print it where I wrote `oops — malformatted data` in the pseudo-code fragment:

```
if ((rc = sscanf(…)) != 8)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Malformatted data (rc = %d): <<%s>>\n", rc, *buf);
}
else
{
    …pick up subtitle from `(*buf)[len]` onwards…
}
```

I use `rc` as a short name for 'return code'.

---

#### Demo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *data[] =
    {
        "00:00:37:09 , 00:00:39:24 , Subtitle Text 1",
        "00:00:31:02,00:00:33:00,Subtitle Text 2",
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]); i++)
    {
        int hh1, mm1, ss1, ms1;
        int hh2, mm2, ss2, ms2;
        int len;
        int rc;
        char **buf = &data[i];

        if ((rc = sscanf(*buf, "%2d:%2d:%2d:%2d , %2d:%2d:%2d:%2d , %n",
                         &hh1, &mm1, &ss1, &ms1, &hh2, &mm2, &ss2, &ms2, &len)) != 8)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Malformatted data (rc = %d): <<%s>>\n", rc, *buf);
        }
        else
        {
            char *subtitle = (*buf) + len;
            printf("%.2d:%.2d:%.2d.%.2d - %.2d:%.2d:%.2d.%.2d = [%s]\n",
                   hh1, mm1, ss1, ms1, hh2, mm2, ss2, ms2, subtitle);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00:00:37.09 - 00:00:39.24 = [Subtitle Text 1]
00:00:31.02 - 00:00:33.00 = [Subtitle Text 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was a bit confused about the optional whitespaces thing.But now its clear :) I also had a doubt..why isn't  len counted in rc?

Comment: Because the C89/C90 standard says it isn't.  There isn't a better, or worse, reason than that.  I suppose that if it is reached in the parsing, it "can't fail", so telling you that it succeeded isn't very helpful.  OTOH, suppose you had a format `"%s x %n"`, it *would* be helpful to know whether the `x` was read...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in above answer, it's always best to present the full code, and also which OS and devkit you're using as there may be differences. I tried your code on Linux with standard cc compiler and found no errors having provoked the input strings a bit (I removed the * before buf since I assumed it wasn't any indirection).

My advice though:
If you don't have control over the exact input format, don't use sscanf()! At least if you wish to create a stable application.